# Typescript @ts-ignore/@ts-expect-error hinder excessive property checks on literals

Tags: typescript

It looks to me that using `// @ts-ignore` and/or `// @ts-expect-error` causes Typescript to misbehave on excess property checks on object literals. All examples below will use `// @ts-ignore` for consistency.

Let's have a simple `type User = {name: string; surname: string }` and create a few literals of this type.

```
const user1: User = {
    name: '123',
    surname: "123",
    nonExistingProp: 'something', // expected error, since it's a non-existing field
};

const user2: User = {
    name: "John",
    surname: 123 // wrong type on a declared field, expected error 
}

const user3: User = {
    name: "Ben",
    surname: 123,
    nonExistingProp: 'something'
}

const user4: User = {
    name: "Rowan",
    // @ts-ignore expected lack of error in the next line, but unexpected lack of error in the last line
    surname: 123,
    nonExistingProp: 'something'
}

const user5: User = {
    name: "Rowan",
    // @ts-ignore expected lack of error in the next line, and also expected error in the last line
    nonExistingProp: 'something'
    surname: 123,
}
```

In the first example we try to add a non-declared field, and in the second one we use a wrong type on a declared field. As expected, we get an error in both.

Things become interesting when we "merge" first and second example to both add non-declared field and use a wrong type on a declared field. In the playground, you will see one error, and AFAIK that's a design decision by creators of TS (to only showcase first error).

What bothers me is the fourth example -- AFAIK `// @ts-ignore` should only affect *one* line below. It seems, though, that it affects two lines, since the error is not displayed on excess `nonExistingProp`.

Interestingly, if we swap two lines (`user5`), `// @ts-ignore` behaves as expected.

What I'm trying to understand is:

- Is this behavior a design decision, and if so, what might be behind that decision
- If not, is this behavior a bug, worth opening an issue for?

I checked TS major versions 3,4,5 and behavior is the same in all of them, so

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQAkCHALYQBcy6YUoA5gNwGHoCuUJ5VNdITBAL4ECCAPYgayNpigBGKhiwBeHCy6VkAcjkAmAMxaANC3acymgER79lk0RASAogA9gNBgAUoYgA5UtdDFyMAALBmNkAHoo5AgXXwgESAATOKgfKCNqUCRkYDBA5DhkRxAAWnj3MAZkGGAIABsUoWZ8UQkpGWhdRVlkVTwHCypLACkxUJA7Uw4NKhto2IB3H35kMABPROQJYuQUpMa4KAg0+qaU7PjE5LP0zOQhEXxxSTBpWX0+lTVh7mQlgAQhBpvZWHMRsgbOCyq5ql4fP5tEEQuF+Fpnu1Xp0Pt0oAAWH5QAZ-YhQywAJTEyzgYJYMWQAAEwOhysB6I5TnEEklUshjggANa7GAPMQk0AbUIoEDxD6NUAQWbmAEw9TONwefjePwBVEQMIRLEdd6faAAVmJpKG5IBVJpdJmREZLLZHK5KBufPugpFYjF0EeUrCsvlAqV2TpaTgjSCPNu-KDEvyIGlKGOUkVco1IHh2vouuRgWChvR9ExRDM82hBnsgiAA)

Comment: ["Working as intended"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42893) apparently.

Comment: Thanks @spender! FWIW I searched for related Qs/issues on SO/Github, but somehow missed that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to repost a [link to a resolved github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42893), linked by @spender -- this is not a bug in typescript.

After some consideration, I understand it in a following way:

In the third example, there is only one error from TS, not two:

```
const user3: User = {
    name: "Ben",
    surname: 123, // error: used type 'number', expected type 'string'
    nonExistingProp: 'something'
}
```

If after `// @ts-expect-error` comment, a new error was to appear, it would probably mean that we should run the compiler twice -- once "before the comment", and once again "after the comment".

Now imagine many (e.g. hundred) `// @ts-expect-error` comments, which maybe also have an effect on one another. How many times would we need to run a compiler then, and in which order? This can quickly become not worth the effort.